# Как правильно оформить согласованное предложение

Tags: общие-вопросы

В ходе проведения индивидуальной профилактической работы было выявлено, что осуществляется контроль родителями за посещением Фёдором занятий во внеурочное время, а также за соблюдением режима дня школьника. Посещение родителями собраний, бесед, участие в делах класса и школы.

Comment: @Анастасteichen, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Какой яркий пример дикого канцелярита! Если действительно хотите улучшить текст, советую избегать отглагольных существительных, заменяя их глаголами: не "осуществляется контроль родителями", а "родители контролируют" и т.п.  Ваш текст труден для понимания, а последнее предложение вообще осталось без сказуемого.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы тут просто поменяла местами слова: "...что родителями осуществляется контроль..." По-моему, так и лучше звучит, и согласуется логичнее.

Comment: Извините, конечно, может я и резко выскажусь, но и без ваших ответов знаю, что это полный канцелярит! Я вопрос задала, как оформить предложение правильно, и ждала не совет, а правильно оформленное предложение как итог нашего общения! Спасибо за внимание...

Comment: Помилуйте, что же тут резкого?  И что значит «оформить предложение правильно»? Оформить означает придать форму некоему содержанию, а содержание вашего текста от меня ускользает (там как минимум не хватает сказуемого, о чем я вам и сообщила, но вы его так и не добавили)  Alex_ander безусловно "разгладил сукно", но не сделал его съедобным, т.е.  удобопонимаемым. «Правильный текст» это когда на другом конце провода  вас понимают именно так, как вам нужно – т.е. получают необходимую информацию, не получая лишней.

Answer (score 0):

Не всё так безнадёжно для делопроизводства. Попробуем "разгладить сукно" минимальными средствами.

В ходе проведения индивидуальной профилактической работы выявлено, что со стороны родителей осуществляется контроль за посещением Фёдором занятий во внеурочное время и за соблюдением им режима дня школьника. При этом имеет место посещение родителями собраний и бесед, просматривается их участие в делах класса и школы.

Comment: То что нужно! Респект и уважуха!